Suitable basemap for sharing Europe Lambert Conformal Conic projection layers to web map
I am trying to share layers with a projection system in Europe Lambert Conformal Conic as a web layer. However, my basemap (World Imagery) is projected in WGS 1984 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere) and I cannot seem to change the projection of the basemap (it is coming from ArcGIS Online). I have tried everything from analysis tools (Project) to restarting ArcGIS Pro, but it did not work.
When I want to share my layer in Europe Lambert I get an error (00230 Service layer has a different projection than the map's projection. When I click on it, it says the basemap is the problem.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how this problem can be solved?

https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/make-a-web-map-without-web-mercator/
